# Most efficient way to scan all possible permutation using Iterators on HashMaps

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, iterator

I want to find the most efficient way to scan all possible permutation using Iterator with HashMaps.

To code I wrote is the following:

```
Iterator<Entry<LinkedList<String>, Record>> iter = treeMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        Entry<LinkedList<String>, Record> entry = iter.next();
        LinkedList<String> rn = entry.getKey();
        Record record = entry.getValue();

        Iterator<Entry<LinkedList<String>, Record>> iter2 = treeMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while(iter2.hasNext())
        {
            Entry<LinkedList<String>, Record> entry2 = iter2.next();
            LinkedList<String> rn2 = entry2.getKey();
            Record record2 = entry2.getValue();

            //DO SOMETHING
        }
     }
```

This is not the best for two reason:

1. Some comparison are repeated more than one time and definitively it's unwanted for my case
2. It's not so efficient

How would you implement this algorithm using Iterators on HashMaps?

Comment: Can you please provide further clarification on this question?  1) The description mentions all possible permutations (implying permutation of all elements in the HashMap), but the sample code doesn't appear to try to do that.  Instead, it appears to try pairing up only the possible combinations of 2 at a time.  2) Is ordering significant?  Do you need to handle the combination [entry1, entry2] differently from [entry2, entry1], or is the difference in ordering unimportant?  3) Can you describe what you need to do in "DO SOMETHING"?  All of this will help inform an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: This looks like an X-Y problem (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem for more).  Even the most efficient possible code running on the fastest available computer wouldn't be able to iterate through the permutations of 30 items in the lifetime of the universe.  Even if you distributed it across all computers on Earth, you couldn't do it for 35 items.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?